# restore from different server on a db2 server

Tags: database, db2-luw

We have a production server and we restored a file system back up of this server on a quality server. 
After the restore, we changed the directory name because here source instance/database name was different than target instance/database name.

we created a configuration file that would be used for initializing the database on the target server.

We uncatalogued the database on the server and started the database instance.

For initializing the database I executed :

```
db2inidb E2Q as snapshot relocate using relocate_e2q_Mar31st_2015
```

But this gave me the error:

```
Relocating database...
DBT1020N  The configuration file contains an invalid entry at line "3". Reason code = "7".
Unable to relocate database, cannot continue
```

the content of the configuration file is :

```
INSTANCE=source_instance,target_instance
DB_NAME=Source_db,target_db
NODENUM=0
<some other source target information>
```

What is wrong in using nodenum=0 here?

I tried to list the db directories but it just gave me one entry of report_db. Also when i tried to list the db directories on the default path, i got the entry:

```
Local Database Directory on <path>
Number of entries in the directory = 1

Database 1 entry:

Database alias = Source_db
Database name = source_db
Database directory = SQL00001
Database release level = d.00
Comment = SAP database Q01
Directory entry type = Home
Catalog database partition number = 0
Database partition number = 0
```

Where am i going wrong? What am i missing?

ps: i am using db2 version 9.7

Comment: Check if there is a space after `NODENUM=0`.

Comment: yes ..i checked that...there is no space....my doubt invloves also the fatct that db2 list db directory should list both the server information and is it not...why is that? what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

According to below manual:

**V9.7 db2relocatedb - Relocate database command**
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0004500.html

**DB_NAME**, **DB_PATH** and **INSTANCE** are required but your configFile does not have **DB_PATH**.  So you may need to add **DB_PATH** at your configFile and try again.

Hope this helps.